# NSDocument class file bundle not copy right

Tags: nsbundle, nsdocument, nsfilewrapper

I created an `NSDocument` base app, which provides a custom file format, which is a bundle containing multiple resources... all works fine, i can save, load, show package contents etc...

the problem is, when i want to sent it over internet, like with gmail, or dropbox... the file shrinks (from KB to bytes) and doesn't state the name of my app, nor 'Show package content works'

```
mdls

kMDItemContentCreationDate     = 2013-11-28 21:29:25 +0000
kMDItemContentModificationDate = 2013-11-28 21:30:06 +0000
kMDItemContentType             = "com.xxx.yyy"
kMDItemContentTypeTree         = (
    "com.xxx.yyy",
    "public.composite-content",
    "public.content",
    "com.apple.package",
    "public.directory",
    "public.item"
)
kMDItemDateAdded               = 2013-11-28 21:30:06 +0000
kMDItemDisplayName             = "FILENAME.ext"
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate     = 2013-11-28 21:30:06 +0000
kMDItemFSCreationDate          = 2013-11-28 21:29:25 +0000
kMDItemFSCreatorCode           = ""
kMDItemFSFinderFlags           = 0
kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon         = (null)
kMDItemFSInvisible             = 0
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden     = 0
kMDItemFSIsStationery          = (null)
kMDItemFSLabel                 = 0
kMDItemFSName                  = "FILENAME.apr"
kMDItemFSNodeCount             = 1
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID          = 20
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID           = 501
kMDItemFSSize                  = 134690
kMDItemFSTypeCode              = ""
kMDItemKind                    = "MyApp"
kMDItemLogicalSize             = 134690
kMDItemPhysicalSize            = 135168
```

MIME
application/x-directory; charset=binary

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending these files around? Are you compressing the wrappers first? A wrapper is just a UNIX directory—if you can’t open your file as a directory on the target machine, you’re just copying it wrong, it’s not an issue with NSDocuments or NBundles or anything.

Comment: the issue is, that, on the production machine, the bundle behaves right, and opens as a file in my application... however, i cannot send it over email